# Google Play App Icon is gone, and cannot be installed

Tags: google-play-store

With a recent update to my Verizon Android Galaxy S4, the Google Play store icon has disappeared from my apps list.

I have done `adb shell pm list packages` and `com.android.vending` is there, but I get the following error when I try to start it with `am start com.android.vending`.

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.android.vending }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.vending }
```

When I tried to re-install it from an `apk` I downloaded, I just get an error indicating that it is already present.

When I try to remove it, I just get`Failure`.

Is there some way to restore `Google Play` short of re-imaging the entire phone?